# How can I determine random time change in Android ICS 4.0.2 based device

Tags: android, performance, android-intent, android-activity

I have an Android ICS based device. Without any app running it will not change time. But whenever I am running one application, it changes the time randomly (mostly 2 days ahead).

There is no set time function is being used to set the device time. This app is written by me. It has many threads on each activity and  1 millisecond timer.

Device has changed its time after 12 hour of run.

Why Device time is changing ? Is this timer or thread which causing problem to change the device time.

```
 public class MainActivity extends Activity {



 TextView DateTextView;
 TextView BatteryTextView;
 String   date;

 Thread mUpdateUIThread;

 int[] m_array ; 
 Timer mTimerThread;

 String StrDdate; 
 int n  = 0;


 public native void WatchDogTimeTest();

 public IntentFilter s_intentFilter;

 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

  DateTextView    = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.DatedisplayTxtVw);
  BatteryTextView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.BatteryStatus);

  date = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy").format(new Date());
  DateTextView.setText(date);

   s_intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
   s_intentFilter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_DATE_CHANGED);
   s_intentFilter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED);
   s_intentFilter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_POWER_CONNECTED);
   s_intentFilter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_POWER_DISCONNECTED);

   this.registerReceiver(this.mBatInfoReceiver,s_intentFilter);


   CreateMutipleThread();
   TimerThread();

  }


 public void CreateMutipleThread()
 {
   for(int i = 0 ; i < 100 ; i++)
   {
   mUpdateUIThread= new Thread() {
      @Override
      public void run() {
        try {
          while (!isInterrupted()) 
          {
            Thread.sleep(1000);   //Check for Aux Battery Status After 10 Second
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable()
            {
              @Override
              public void run() 
              {
                  n++;

                  if(n >= 10000)
                      n= 0;
              }
            });
          }
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
       }
      }
    };
    mUpdateUIThread.start();
 }
}

 public void TimerThread()
   { 

mTimerThread = new Timer();
//Set the schedule function and rate
mTimerThread.schedule(new TimerTask() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        StrDdate = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy").format(new Date());
        //Log.d("TimeDevice","Time"+StrDdate);
    }      
  },1000,1);  
 }

public void InvalidateTimer()
   {
  this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        printTime();
    }
  });

 } 

 public void printTime()
 {

 }


  public BroadcastReceiver mBatInfoReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver(){

  @Override
  public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent intent) {

    final String action  = intent.getAction();

    //Date Change Broad cast
    if(action.equals(Intent.ACTION_DATE_CHANGED))
    {
        String mydate    java.text.DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance().format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
         date = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy").format(new Date());
         DateTextView.setText(date);
         DateTextView.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
         BatteryTextView.setText(mydate);
    }

  }
 };
 }
```

Comment: `Without any app running it will not change time` - huh?

Comment: Ya Simon. Any idea? Is this ICS problem or App is causing problem?

Comment: What does this line do? `System.loadLibrary("timetestissue");`? If you don't know if your code is changing the time on the device, maybe you should take a look at your code, to fully understand it. I'm guessing you haven't wrote it all on your own?

Comment: I had added jni layer also but no call is going to JNI layer

Comment: @Chris I am able to fetch the current date No issue. Only thing I am not able to understand date is changing after some 14 hour of continuous log run. Any of this code is causing problem.